# How to let Hockeyapp collect Crash Reports of a Service?

Tags: android, service, background, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I added the HockeyApp SDK to my Android App. This works as expected, and I also get crash reports of the main activity and the associated classes.

However, I did not figure out how I will get crash reports of the [in my case started & bound] Service. The UpdateManager only accepts Activities and is defined as

```
UpdateManager.register(Activity, String)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient when the *Activity* calls the appropriate methods of the *UpdateManager*. The *Service* must only register the *CrashManager* by adding this line in e.g. *onCreate()*

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    CrashManager.register(this, HOCKEY_APP_ID);
}
```

*HOCKEY_APP_ID* is the same ID as used in the *Activity*.

However, the crash of the Service will only be committed to HockeyApp when the Activity restarts.

Comment: I added a catch of `WindowManager.BadTokenException` because the register call will create a dialog when it finds previous crashes. Otherwise the service will crash the next time again.

Comment: @Roel you have to subclass the CrashManagerListener and say             `@Override public boolean shouldAutoUploadCrashes() { return true; }` because then it won't try to show the dialog