# How to read Crash log and find clue on Xamarin.forms' iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using XF PCL.
On my iOS app, it crashes sometimes while it's on background.

I found crash log on my iPhone and look.
But It's hard to understand nor find where was the problem.

Here is my crash log.
There is nothing about my code but xamarins's api or Native api.

I believe my code cause this problem but couldn't find the start line.
What can I get from this crash log?

Thanks.

```
Incident Identifier: CE060E55-0908-4BB9-AD6------
CrashReporter Key:   ccb636455a06b10ce38a22cdae9e204f4b28e79c
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             allbX.iOS [337]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/-----30B1-4F7A-A5EC-----/allbX.iOS.app/allbX.iOS
Identifier:          com.----.allb
Version:             69 (1.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.----.allb [427]


Date/Time:           2016-11-17 17:06:31.4329 +0900
Launch Time:         2016-11-17 16:37:02.7326 +0900
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa2014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019006a450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018ff163e0 abort + 140
3   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010024cab0 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2420)
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000190064348 _sigtramp + 52
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019006a450 pthread_kill + 112
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018ff163e0 abort + 140
7   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100354bd0 print_all_exceptions(MonoObject*) (runtime.m:997)
8   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010024d1e8 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (mini-exceptions.c:2873)
9   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010024c744 mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:1798)
10  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010024b824 mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:2027)
11  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100244348 mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm64.c:390)
12  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a78cb8 throw_exception + 168
13  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010025b630 mono_magic_trampoline (mini-trampolines.c:833)
14  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a77d9c generic_trampoline_jit + 252
15  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a31274 wrapper_managed_to_native_object___icall_wrapper_ves_icall_array_new_specific_intptr_int + 180
16  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100e09db8 System_Collections_Generic_Queue_1_T_REF_SetCapacity_int (queue.cs:314)
17  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100e09418 System_Collections_Generic_Queue_1_T_REF_Enqueue_T_REF (queue.cs:207)
18  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000101922e40 Xamarin_Forms_Element__VisibleDescendantsd__95_MoveNext (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:500)
19  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001018bb8a4 Xamarin_Forms_Layout_ShouldLayoutChildren (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:423)
20  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001018b8594 Xamarin_Forms_Layout_UpdateChildrenLayout (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:211)
21  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001018b8350 Xamarin_Forms_Layout_OnSizeAllocated_double_double (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:195)
22  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001018c8ff8 Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_SizeAllocated_double_double (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:630)
23  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000101923a08 Xamarin_Forms_Layout__c__OnChildMeasureInvalidatedb__39_0 (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:326)
24  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000101ead8e4 Foundation_NSAsyncActionDispatcher_Apply (NSAction.cs:163)
25  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a2c5d4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
26  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002598a8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2524)
27  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bbb84 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2809)
28  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bbae0 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2967)
29  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010367c10c native_to_managed_trampoline_11(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, char const*, char const*) (registrar.m:481)
30  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000103687e0c -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] (registrar.m:25787)
31  Foundation                      0x0000000191abb65c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f80278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7fbc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7d7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190eac048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
36  GraphicsServices                0x0000000192932198 GSEventRunModal + 180
37  UIKit                           0x0000000196e982fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
38  UIKit                           0x0000000196e93034 UIApplicationMain + 208
39  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000102624724 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (/<unknown>:1)
40  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000102022a1c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr (UIApplication.cs:79)
41  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001020228dc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
42  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100360630 allbX_iOS_Application_Main_string__ (Main.cs:18)
43  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a2c5d4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
44  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002598a8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2524)
45  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bbb84 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2809)
46  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bdd04 mono_runtime_exec_main (object.c:4585)
47  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bd920 mono_runtime_run_main (object.c:4134)
48  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100243b34 mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1048)
49  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010035facc xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:487)
50  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010370e2dc main (main.arm64.m:209)
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018fe905b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018f9913ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019575e548 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019575e4bc bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019575e39c std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019575e64c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff8416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff83fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190eac048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   WebCore                         0x0000000195a5c45c RunWebThread(void*) + 456
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff8416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff83fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190eac048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000019169dfd0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191abb47c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  SGen worker
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100313acc thread_func (mono-os-mutex.h:108)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Finalizer
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff841a8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002878fc finalizer_thread (mono-os-semaphore.h:73)
2   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8c30 start_wrapper (threads.c:740)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff8416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff83fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190eac048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x00000001919bda8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001919de57c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019780da2c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000191abb47c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  Timer-Scheduler
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010031999c mono_os_cond_timedwait (mono-os-mutex.h:108)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010031966c _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handles.c:1555)
4   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100329358 wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (wait.c:189)
5   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e4a34 mono_wait_uninterrupted (threads.c:1595)
6   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e4cc4 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (threads.c:1731)
7   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c9cc8 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal_intptr_int + 104
8   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c9c10 System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool + 80
9   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c8cac System_Threading_WaitHandle_InternalWaitOne_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_long_bool_bool + 60
10  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c8c5c System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_long_bool + 44
11  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c8a7c System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int_bool + 60
12  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007c8bdc System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int + 44
13  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010090fe84 System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread + 1396
14  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bea10 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object + 192
15  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bc17c System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 428
16  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bbfbc System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 44
17  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bbf34 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object + 84
18  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007beb64 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart + 52
19  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a2c5d4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
20  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002598a8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2524)
21  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bbb84 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2809)
22  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8cac start_wrapper (threads.c:747)
23  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  RLMRealm notification listener
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff88630 kevent + 8
1   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100066cdc realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 212
2   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100066ed4 std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>::operator()() + 28
3   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100066e5c std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::__execute() + 28
4   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100067024 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >*> >(void*, void*) + 84
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  tid_b207
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010031999c mono_os_cond_timedwait (mono-os-mutex.h:108)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010031966c _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handles.c:1555)
4   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100329358 wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (wait.c:189)
5   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002b364c ves_icall_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait (monitor.c:1288)
6   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bdc68 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait_object_int + 104
7   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bdd14 System_Threading_Monitor_ObjWait_bool_int_object + 84
8   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bd78c System_Threading_Monitor_Wait_object_int_bool + 44
9   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bd820 System_Threading_Monitor_Wait_object_int + 32
10  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010078e648 System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_WaitUntilCountOrTimeout_int_uint_System_Threading_CancellationToken + 120
11  allbX.iOS                       0x000000010078e3ec System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_Wait_int_System_Threading_CancellationToken + 412
12  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100f380a4 System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_T_REF_TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation_T_REF__int_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource (BlockingCollection.cs:712)
13  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100f37f58 System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_T_REF_TryTake_T_REF__int_System_Threading_CancellationToken (BlockingCollection.cs:667)
14  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100f37cec System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_T_REF_Take (BlockingCollection.cs:554)
15  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000101b51fe4 Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_CADisplayLinkTicker_StartThread (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CADisplayLinkTicker.cs:52)
16  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bea10 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object + 192
17  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bc17c System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 428
18  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bbfbc System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 44
19  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007bbf34 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object + 84
20  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001007beb64 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart + 52
21  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100a2c5d4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
22  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002598a8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2524)
23  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002bbb84 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2809)
24  allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8cac start_wrapper (threads.c:747)
25  allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff8416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff83fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190f7d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190eac048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001aa6a5fe8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001aa6cbf14 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e22e0 worker_thread (mono-os-mutex.h:136)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8c30 start_wrapper (threads.c:740)
4   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e22e0 worker_thread (mono-os-mutex.h:136)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8c30 start_wrapper (threads.c:740)
4   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  tid_1557
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 name:  tid_b017
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ffa1e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001900679c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   allbX.iOS                       0x000000010033b6c4 mono_thread_info_sleep (mono-os-mutex.h:137)
3   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e18b8 monitor_thread (threadpool-ms.c:905)
4   allbX.iOS                       0x00000001002e8c30 start_wrapper (threads.c:740)
5   allbX.iOS                       0x0000000100337998 inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068850 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190068760 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065dac thread_start + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190065da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000036
    x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016fdaeae0   x6: 0x0000000000000031   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000190064314  x11: 0x000000010aa10000
   x12: 0xffffffffffffc000  x13: 0x000000010aa0c000  x14: 0x0000000004000020  x15: 0x0000000000005848
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000190ecb5a0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b605bc40  x21: 0x000000010373bd2b  x22: 0x000000010373bd88  x23: 0x5bbf5b5ad2a000e0
   x24: 0x000000016fdaef18  x25: 0x000000010373bd3b  x26: 0x00000001190f5b88  x27: 0x000000010ae48bb0
   x28: 0x000000010a80a1f0   fp: 0x000000016fdaeeb0   lr: 0x000000019006a450
    sp: 0x000000016fdaee90   pc: 0x000000018ffa2014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x10004c000 - 0x1038ebfff allbX.iOS arm64  <b735db1d924c31c9a66b0c776b678102> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/-------30B1-4F7A-A5EC------/allbX.iOS.app/allbX.iOS
0x109ef4000 - 0x109f23fff dyld arm64  <f5a894bbb0cc38b1930add2172007394> /usr/lib/dyld
0x109f78000 - 0x10a3c3fff libSkiaSharp arm64  <2f0e83ff66c0338dbaf79398b01e0785> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C69D829-30B1-4F7A-A5EC-171C2108DFBF/allbX.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp
0x11572c000 - 0x11572ffff Pegasus arm64  <8fc9362449b436b883c359d5e8555bed> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/Pegasus.axbundle/Pegasus
0x115738000 - 0x115743fff ContactsUI arm64  <73928fb30eeb311e8a95437f2f77eb79> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/ContactsUI.axbundle/ContactsUI
0x115754000 - 0x115757fff WeatherFoundation arm64  <9486354cd3183e909c56294e3a916751> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/WeatherFoundation.axbundle/WeatherFoundation
0x115760000 - 0x115763fff TwitterFramework arm64  <02a4564942c431d79660de033212188d> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TwitterFramework.axbundle/TwitterFramework
0x11576c000 - 0x11576ffff PDFKit arm64  <6fd632a57f30377781b27a89df818078> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/PDFKit.axbundle/PDFKit
0x115778000 - 0x11577bfff GameCenterUIFramework arm64  <364baf5f62c03f608ad3020b238b79ba> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GameCenterUIFramework.axbundle/GameCenterUIFramework
0x115784000 - 0x115797fff EventKitUIFramework arm64  <89ef1b5f49393345ad29e3ababf44e90> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/EventKitUIFramework.axbundle/EventKitUIFramework
0x1157c0000 - 0x1157c7fff SafariServices arm64  <ed8550f474f137a4bd07511b22f1d2ac> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SafariServices.axbundle/SafariServices
0x1157d4000 - 0x1157d7fff SpringBoardFoundation arm64  <ac308c6ce60139c9b5dc4ddcfe385908> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SpringBoardFoundation.axbundle/SpringBoardFoundation
0x1157e0000 - 0x115813fff VectorKit arm64  <a4c9b38fa5093ed49f3ba12ce3d65957> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit
0x115838000 - 0x11583bfff SpriteKit arm64  <09294776a0d9379fb6358195d37ce42e> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SpriteKit.axbundle/SpriteKit
0x115844000 - 0x11584ffff PreferencesFramework arm64  <91680771b1f53afe8791b8d2052443ef> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/PreferencesFramework.axbundle/PreferencesFramework
0x115860000 - 0x115863fff CoreSuggestionsUI arm64
```

...

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271421/exception-type-exc-crash-sigabrt your app is killed by system routine

Comment: @Mr.L Hi L. Thanks for the link. But i don't still understand. So it's killed because my code is wrong somewhere? The link says something like that. What' difference between crash and what he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into Mr. L's comment for the root cause of the issue but in order to better understand the crash logs from iOS, you must symbolicate them using files within your ipa file (which is the one you sent to Apple when pushing out an update for your app to the App Store).

Xamarin's info is [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash/), specifically check out the 2 links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: The link you gave me is helpful. But I couldn't succeed to analyze it. I followed making symbolicate and analyze but the result file is exactly same. I'll try again.

Comment: I will take a look more. But If I succeed to symbolicate it, can I see where my Xamarin.Forms code is wrong? I'm asking it because I'm afraid it's Xamarin not pure Native.

Comment: @BrightLee Does the error not happen while debugging the app?

Comment: I could not see it so far while debugging.

Comment: @BrightLee What I would suggest is creating a new HockeyApp account, setting up a new app on their site, installing their plugin, adding like 4 lines of code to your iOS project (and Android if you want) and then you will have automatic crash reporting and if you upload the correct files to the HockeyApp site when you setup your app, they will automatically symbolicate the crash log. If you need to see code and/or links for how to set it up, I can edit my answer. And it works with a service [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26096918/3850012)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I also thought implementing HockeyApp, but I changed my mind after I saw reviews in Component Store that saying about HockeyApp. Many people says like "A crash report tool(HockeyApp) cause a crash." If so, It would be a joke. But I wanna listen to you. Have you used HockeyApp on your live app?

Comment: There are lots of one star reviews.

Comment: Especially on Hockeyapp for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: @BrightLee I have used it but not extensively, only on a side project, so yea I would be wary if there were a lot of bad reviews. You would need to do a lot of testing. Also make sure the reviews are not from a long time ago. I know they have made quite a few changes recently, but even if you only used it on a beta version of your app so you could collect the stack trace and then you uninstalled it... Might be a lot of work through just for a stack trace

Comment: yes it's reviews for recently updated version. But your suggestion could be an option to solve the problems. Thanks.

Comment: @BrightLee Sure thing. Wish I could have helped more. Let me know if you have issue with HockeyApp if you decide to try it.